How to decrypt or decode unknown file formats?
I have got a new challange. I hvae some log files that mostly contain android device modem and ap logs.
The file extension varies depending on the chipset. There is specific tool provided by the chipset manufacturers to open those logs and see inside manually.
But I want to build a log analysis tool that will read and analyse those log files. For that I first need to decrypt or decode the information in those log files.
I have no idea how should I proceed. Can anyone help?

You need to know how it was encoded.

If you have a working device that creates such logs I would start tracing down the process that created hose files. Once you have identified the process you can download the executable and libraries and decompile them e.g. in Ghidra to find where the logs are created.

Try static analysis in radare2.
Use ptrace to trace call origin and cross references.
Use hex editor to get header bytes to determine file type.
